# Fluent Nhibernate: ignore interfaces/abstract classes during BuildSchema or UpdateSchema

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

**Edit**

I've got an interface that I'd like to base some classes on. When I go to BuildSchema (or UpdateSchema), Nhibernate creates a table for the interface. I thought I found a work-around as follows:

The Interface and Classes:

```
public interface ILevel
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
public abstract class Level : ILevel
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
public class LevelOne : Level { }
public class LevelTwo : Level { }
```

The Mappings:

```
public class LevelMap : ClassMap<ILevel>
{
    public LevelMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}
public class LevelOneMap : SubclassMap<LevelOne>
{
}
public class LevelTwoMap : SubclassMap<LevelTwo>
{
}
```

**This doesn't work** (I did another UpdateSchema and the pesky ILevel table appeared).

Is there a configuration I'm unaware of to ignore interfaces/abstract classes altogether?

Comment: What kind of result do you want? Two tables for LevelOne and LevelTwo with the properties of Level/ILevel? Then you have to use ClassMap only.

Comment: Yes, that's the goal. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For seperate tables LevelOne and LevelTwo, that both have the properties of Level/ILevel, use a generic mapping for Level:

```
public abstract class LevelMap<T> : ClassMap<T>
    where T : Level  // ILevel should work, too
{
    protected LevelMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}

public class LevelOneMap : LevelMap<LevelOne>
{
}

public class LevelTwoMap : LevelMap<LevelTwo>
{
}
```

You provide two separate class mappings without telling Fluent the real class hierarchy.