# Ignore Property in FluentNHibernate AutoMapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I have for each Entity a BaseClass and a concrete class.

For Example:

ContactBase

Contact

Contact inherits ContactBase.
In Contact, I can override properties of ContactBase. The Problem is now, that FluentNHibernate will map this property twice.
How can I avoid this to map properties which are in the concrete class and overrides the one from the base class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more about your models and mapping attempts... perhaps [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693497/fluent-nhibernate-ignore-interfaces-abstract-classes-during-buildschema-or-upda) could be of use. The problem seems different but the solution might be the same.